# Using Google Play Services on lower end tablet

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I'm an android developer and I want to make an application that uses Google Maps API V2 to provide an interactive map. As I'm on a budget I bought a tablet for around £49 and it doesn't have Google Play store it has Amazon App Store.

My question is, can I use the Google Maps API V2 with this device or will I not be able to utilise such services? If I can't, is there a way to install Google Play Store and Services onto my device?

Answer (score 0):

> can I use the Google Maps API V2 with this device or will I not be able to utilise such services?

You cannot use the Play Services, including Maps V2, on such a device.

> If I can't, is there a way to install Google Play Store and Services onto my device?

Google does not distribute these, except to device manufacturers who license them. Anyone else who distributes them is distributing them in violation of Google's copyright (a.k.a., a "software pirate").

You may wish to consider using alternative solutions that *are* available for your device and others that lack the Play Services, such as integrating OpenStreetMap for your maps.